# JavaFX: Best practice for navigating between UI screens

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scene, stage

I want to change UI screens from `login.fxml` to `home.fxml`.

Should I change the `Stage` or the `Scene`? I'm not sure which is the best practice?
Also, can I use a lambda expression for the handler in the controller?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: I requested an example demonstrating the problem because I want to know what you've tried so far. This is a question I would expect you could answer yourself through some introductory tutorials or a little tinkering on your part.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, let's start out with the `Stage` .vs. `Scene` issue:

As known, the `JavaFX` hierarchy is based on: `Stage` -> `Scene` -> `Nodes` (etc).

See here:

[image]

Practically speaking, a rule-of-thumb in my opinion is **the future**:

- If you plan on going forward to a different *place* in the flow of your program (login -> profile, for example) - change the `Stage`.
- If you are in the same *enviroment* (login for the first time -> login after multiple wrong tries) - change the `Scene`.

**As for lambdas**: Ahhmmm... if your current `Java`/`JavaFX` version has the abillity - there is no reason not to use.
For more about controller handlers in
 Java 8,  see this [great tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-event-handling-examples/).

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably stick for the Old-School version for now as I'm beginning out and implement lambdas later when I'm more comfortable with JavaFX

Answer (score 6):

I use this approach for changing scenes in `JavaFX`:

```
/**
 * Controller class for menuFrame.fxml
 */
public class MenuFrameControl implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Button sceneButton1;
    @FXML private Button sceneButton2;
    @FXML private Button sceneButton3;

   /**
     * Event handling method, loads new scene from .fxml file
     * according to clicked button and initialize all components.
     * @param event
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @FXML
    private void handleMenuButtonAction (ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Stage stage = null;
        Parent myNewScene = null;

        if (event.getSource() == sceneButton1){
            stage = (Stage) sceneButton1.getScene().getWindow();
            myNewScene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/mvc/view/scene1.fxml"));
        } else if (event.getSource() == sceneButton2){
            stage = (Stage) flightBtn.getScene().getWindow();
            myNewScene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/mvc/view/scene2.fxml"));
        } else if (event.getSource() == sceneButton3) {
            stage=(Stage) staffBtn.getScene().getWindow();
            myNewScene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/mvc/view/scene3.fxml"));
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(myNewScene);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("My New Scene");
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) { }
```

So basically when you click the button, it saves actually displayed `Stage` object into `stage` variable. Then it loads new `Scene` object from .fxml file into `myNewScene` variable and then put this fresh loaded `Scene` object into your saved `Stage` object.

With this code you can make basic three button menu, where each button switch to different scene, using just single `Stage` object.